# DocuSign API: Email body (blurb) defaults with account name and email at the top, how do I remove?

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm using the PHP DocuSign library to create a document via an existing PDF, setting the signature and text fields, and setting the email subject and body.

However, when setting the body of the email, I can't get rid of my name and email address appearing at the top of the body.

[image: Email created through API]

Is there a way to get rid of that default text appearing? I've pored over the package classes and can't seem to find any methods other than setEmailSubject and setEmailBlurb. I've also checked the settings on my DocuSign account and I can't find anything notable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docusign lets you create your own branding for the emails and lets you upload your own resource files. See more information [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-email-resource-file-v1-1)

You can then specify a BrandId  in your [createEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#branding-an-envelope) request so that you can send customized emails for the envelope.

Comment: Awesome, so you were pretty much spot on. I had to go into my docusign account and create a new Brand, which is under the admin panel. From there I click Brands, create a new Brand, and under the section "advanced configuration" I click on resource files. From there I download the default email XML and edit to remove the instances of the header in the XML. From there I simply upload my edited XML, and set this new brand as the default. This fixes my issues. Thanks.